# Trouble checking if url param exists

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to find if my url parameters exist or not.

I have tried the following:

```
 // doesn't work
(Request.QueryString["showTop"] != "" && Request.QueryString["showTop"] != null)
 // doesn't work
(Request.Params["showTop"] != "" && Request.Params["showTop"] != null)
```

I am trying to find the correct value. The full statement looks like:

```
showTop = (Request.QueryString["showTop"] != "" &&
           Request.QueryString["showTop"] != null) ? 
                     Request.QueryString["showTop"]  : (10).ToString();
```

Which works fine, **if** showTop exists with a value.

This is being done within the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
showTop = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["showTop"]) ? "10" : Request["showTop"];
```

Assuming you want "showTop"to default to "10".

Answer (score 0):

First check whether QueryString has keys or not by calling this method.

```
bool qKeys = Request.QueryString.HasKeys();
```